# How to align grid elements to the right column?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I have a fixed number of columns in a CSS grid display, and elements to put in these columns. The number of elements to put is smaller than the number of columns.

I would like the columns to be aligned to the right, in the order where the elements were added. In the code below, 4 elements are aligned to the left, and the other 6 are empty to their right:

```css
.hello {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 5rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">1</div>
  <div class="hello">2</div>
  <div class="hello">3</div>
  <div class="hello">4</div>
</div>
```

I would like to change this display from the one above:

```
1    2    3    4    empty  empty  empty  empty  empty  empty
```

to

```
empty  empty  empty  empty  empty  empty   1    2    3    4
```

I [tried](https://grid.malven.co/) all kinds of combinations of `align`, `justify-content` but none of them work right. Is this possible with CSS Grid?

Comment: doable but only in a hacky way, this is a Flexbox job not a CSS grid one

Comment: Is there a reason you need the ten columns, because the easiest way would be to avoid generating empty columns, and simply use `margin-left: auto` (or `margin-inline-start: auto`, if you want it to update according to the user's language settings) on the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the number is limited, you can define all of them manually

```css
.hello {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 3rem);
  margin: 5px;
}

.container > :nth-last-child(1) {grid-column-end: -1}
.container > :nth-last-child(2) {grid-column-end: -2}
.container > :nth-last-child(3) {grid-column-end: -3}
.container > :nth-last-child(4) {grid-column-end: -4}
.container > :nth-last-child(5) {grid-column-end: -5}
.container > :nth-last-child(6) {grid-column-end: -6}
.container > :nth-last-child(7) {grid-column-end: -7}
.container > :nth-last-child(8) {grid-column-end: -8}
.container > :nth-last-child(9) {grid-column-end: -9}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">1</div>
  <div class="hello">2</div>
  <div class="hello">3</div>
  <div class="hello">4</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">1</div>
  <div class="hello">2</div>
  <div class="hello">3</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">1</div>
  <div class="hello">2</div>
  <div class="hello">3</div>
  <div class="hello">4</div>
  <div class="hello">5</div>
  <div class="hello">6</div>
</div>
```

But better use flexbox:

```css
.hello {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  width: 3rem;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  width: calc(10*3rem + 9*5px);
  margin: 5px;
}

.container > :first-child {margin-left:auto}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">1</div>
  <div class="hello">2</div>
  <div class="hello">3</div>
  <div class="hello">4</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">1</div>
  <div class="hello">2</div>
  <div class="hello">3</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">1</div>
  <div class="hello">2</div>
  <div class="hello">3</div>
  <div class="hello">4</div>
  <div class="hello">5</div>
  <div class="hello">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Thank you, this is very comprehensive**. I should have been more precise with my question (I know the total number of columns, but the width of each element will be reactive, i.e. `auto` instead of `5rem`). This makes the grid version doable (because it does not depend on the width of the element), but for the flexbox one I would need somehow to take into account the size of the parent.

Comment: @WoJ such information is crucial and should be within your question. I wouldn't have added this answer if the size was auto and not fixed. Always add your *real* use case not a simplified version that is far from your *real* use case

Comment: Yes I should have done it (it is the effect of my trials on JSFiddle) but your other solution is very much useful. I would not have known that a flexbox approach is possible with the computation. Please do not remove it! (I took a snapshot just in case :) :))

Answer (score 0):

How about adding empty elements to fill the grid?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  
  margin: 8px auto;
  width: min-content;
  border: solid 2px red;
  padding: 4px;
}

.container>div {
  border: solid 2px green;
  padding: 4px 12px;
}

.container>div:empty {
  order: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, this is a good idea... Since I will be generating the divs with Vue, I can conditionally drop empty divs. Thanks! (I modified the code to put the empty divs at the beginning - which is what I am looking for)

Comment: I was glad to help. But reverted code to its original state, otherwise my answer loses its meaning, especially `order: -1;`.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.hello {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  
  min-width:20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello"></div>
  <div class="hello"></div>
  <div class="hello"></div>
  <div class="hello"></div>
  <div class="hello"></div>
  <div class="hello"></div>
  <div class="hello">1</div>
  <div class="hello">2</div>
  <div class="hello">3</div>
  <div class="hello">4</div>

</div>
```

If your number of empty rows are dynamic,You should use javascript/jquery/ts for creating DIVs that will repeat

Used **Flex** instead of GRID.

Gap is the distance between flex elements.You can adjust it however u want.

```
justify-content:flex-end;
```

used For aligning all Divs to the right.

min-width:20px; is added so that to show that divs wil have a minimum width.

**`Flex=1`** can be used so that all the divs inside flex have equal width.
`flex: 1;` in **.hello** Class

Comment: I've moved your code to the code player - you can see that the numbers run in reverse - which is not what I showed in my question

Comment: You've changed your code but now it is just empty divs and then my sequence, aligned. I do not see how this answers the question.

Comment: Iam Sorry.If I haven't got it clearly.Can u explain WHat u want to achieve in detail?Or IF you could Pls update your question.
Do you want a calendar like structure where you have fixed no. of columns and you have to fill empty spaces before 1st day.